# USB Joystick on wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, gamepad

I have ubuntu 14.04 and latest version of wine installed on my system.

I recently installed Assassin's creed on my system with help of Playonlinux. I installed xboxdrv and configured my USB gamepad.

Also activated through terminal command however it still is not being read by Assassin's creed when the game starts.

Any clues where to find the ans?

Answer (score 8):

Try using the command

```
wine control
```

This should bring up the Wine Control Panel where you will find the game controllers icon. Check the configuration for **Game Controllers**.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had another game that saw my gamepad but seemed to ignore the calibrations I had carefully set up with jstest-gtk. Running wine control allowed me to disable the /dev/input/event* interface for that game, leaving /dev/input/js0 (and its calibrated settings) as the only one the game could use.

Comment: Here is my explanation how to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix/1438603#1438603