# 22.04 The xbox controller of wine has a mistake, how to fix?

Tags: drivers, wine, ubuntu-drivers, xbox-360, xbox-one

1. First of all, I installed `wine` following the steps from [this website](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-wine-linux/) without installing about `winehq` [because of this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411024/unable-to-open-winecfg/1438203#1438203), and also installing more typing these commands:

`$ sudo apt-get install wine32`

`$ sudo apt-get install winetricks`

`$ winetricks dotnet45`

`$ export WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine"`

`$ wineboot`

2. I typed the command `wine64 uninstaller` to add packages:

- [wine-mono-7.4.0.msi](https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/)
- [wine-gecko-2.47.2-x86.msi](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko) and [wine-gecko-2.47.2-x86_64.msi](https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko)
- [.NET-Desktop-Runtime-6.0.10-x86](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) and [.NET-Desktop-Runtime-6.0.10-x64](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)
- [xi.win7.x86.en.msi](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/1843-directinput-force-feedback-driver-for-xinput-masahiko-morii/) (The original driver of my xbox360 joystick)
- [xi.win7.x64.en.msi](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/1843-directinput-force-feedback-driver-for-xinput-masahiko-morii/) (I couldn't install, so repair option instead)

3. I followed the steps of the `xboxdrv`'s installation from [this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695069/xbox-controller-blinking/1438948#1438948) to work with my xbox 360 joystick.
4. I installed [open-joystick-display-2.8.0-x64-linux.deb](https://archive.org/download/open-joystick-display) to check the input of my xbox360 joystick:

[image: Gamepad_Ubuntu]

5. I installed [open-joystick-display-2.8.0-x64-windows.exe](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Streaming/Open-Joystick-Display.shtml) by wine to check the input of my xbox360 joystick:

[image: Gamepad_wine]

6. I typed the commands to check the difference between controllers of Ubuntu (left side) and wine (right side):

`$ jstest.gtk`

`$ wine control joy.cpl`

- I checked that the controller of Ubuntu is working fine, and the controller of wine has a mistake, for example as the above picture that instead of four axes, it's four buttons and besides, the Rz axe is not working at all.

[image: Gampepad_Ubuntu-wine]

Could anyone tell me how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I figured out that the problem is in wine's `Registry Editor` and it doesn't need any driver to be installed, so I removed `DirectInput Force Feedback Driver for XInput - Masahiko Morii` that belongs to `xi.win7.x86.en.msi` and `xi.win7.x64.en.msi` (that I've installed before) just typing in Terminal: `wine64 uninstaller`

I solved the problem following the steps from [this website](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/hxfevf/hotas_style_joysticks_in_wine_with_not_all_axes/); First of all, go to wine's `Registry Editor` just typing in terminal:

`$ wine regedit`

And then, go to the key path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Wine -> DirectInput` and right-click in the right window and select `New -> String Value`, set the SAME name of the joystick controller in wine as shown [the above picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK3Yg.jpg), in my case it's `Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) (event)` and set the same value of all sticks as shown the same picture in the string:

- First stick: `X,Y`
- Second stick: `Rx,Ry`
- Third stick: `Z,Rz`
- Fourth stick: `POV`

So the value without any blank space to set in the string is: `X,Y,Rx,Ry,Z,Rz,POV1` (I added the number `1` next to `POV` to work the controller)

[image]

Finally, following the steps from [this website](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/hxfevf/comment/icved46/); In the `Registry Editor`, go to the key path `HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE -> System -> CurrentControlSet -> Services -> winebus`, right-click in the right window and select `New -> Key` and set the name `Map`, click the `Map` key in the left window, and then right-click in the right window and select `New -> String Value`, set the SAME name of joystick controller in wine and set the value of `Mapping String` (Here is an explanation at the bottom how to get) and close the `Registry Editor`, that's all. To test the joystick controller in wine, type in Terminal:

`$ wine control joy.cpl`

[image]

I installed the app called `SDL2 Gamepad Tool` that I downloaded for Linux from [this website](https://generalarcade.com/gamepadtool/); Open the app and click `[Create A New Mapping]` with the same name of joystick controller in wine, not Ubuntu (I put the different name as `xbox360` by mistake, but it was not problem) and then click `[Copy Mapping String]`, this is the value that I got:

- `0000000058626f782047616d65706100,xbox360,a:b0,b:b1,x:b2,y:b3,back:b6,guide:b8,start:b7,leftstick:b9,rightstick:b10,leftshoulder:b4,rightshoulder:b5,dpup:h0.1,dpdown:h0.4,dpleft:h0.8,dpright:h0.2,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a2,righty:a3,lefttrigger:a5,righttrigger:a4,platform:Linux,`

I changed the name `xbox360` in this value into `Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) (event)` to fix my mistake.

The alternative to `SDL2 Gamepad Tool` is `AntiMicroX`, it also generates the value of `Mapping String` but a little difference of the `Gamepad GUID` value only two digits at the end:

- `0000000058626f782047616d65706100` from SDL2 Gamepad Tool
- `0000000058626f782047616d6570610000` from AntiMicroX

[image]

Installing `AntiMicroX` is to type in Terminal:

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryochan7/antimicro`

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install antimicro`

More info about how to use AntiMicroX, [in this website](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-antimicrox-gamepad-mapper-linux/).

[image]